# Kotlin Passing ListArray to another Activity using Parcelable

Tags: android, class, arraylist, kotlin, parcelable

I have a custom class filled with information of a User. I use an ArrayList to hold all the User class data. I would like to pass the array to another activity where the it can be read and modified. Since the array could be large, I need this process to be done as efficiently and fast as possible, which is why I choose to use Parcelable instead of Serializable.

I am having trouble doing this using Kotlin. There are lots of Java tutorials but none are in Kotlin, which is what makes this question different then all the others. Can someone please provide and explain the code in Kotlin on how this can be achieved?

This is what I have so far:

```
constructor(`in`:Parcel) {
    CollegeName = `in`.readString()
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {

}

private fun readFromParcel(`in`:Parcel) {
    CollegeName = `in`.readString()
}

companion object {
    @JvmField final val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<College> = object: Parcelable.Creator<College> {

        override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): College {
            return College(source)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<College?> {
            return arrayOfNulls<College>(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: Android Studio has a feature where you can paste Java code into a Kotlin class and it will convert it to Kotlin. This might be enough to help you solve the issue

Comment: I don't know what to do or what code to use. There is no Kotlin tutorials on how to do this

Comment: The problem is that I want it be be in Kotlin, not Java, so it is not a duplicate of the link above.

Comment: Can you add some code? For example: the data that you want to transfer between activities?

Comment: Okay code has been added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use something like this...

```
   class Series() : Parcelable {
  private var name: String? = null
  private var numOfSeason: Int = 0
  private var numOfEpisode: Int = 0

  constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {
    val data = arrayOfNulls<String>(3)
    parcel.readStringArray(data)
    this.name = data[0]
    this.numOfSeason = Integer.parseInt(data[1])
    this.numOfEpisode = Integer.parseInt(data[2])
  }


  override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeString(name);
    parcel.writeInt(numOfSeason);
    parcel.writeInt(numOfEpisode);
  }

  private fun readFromParcel(parcel: Parcel){
    name = parcel.readString()
    numOfSeason = parcel.readInt()
    numOfEpisode = parcel.readInt()
  }
  override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
  }

  companion object CREATOR : Creator<Series> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Series {
      return Series(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Series?> {
      return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
  }

}
```

and then in your Activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        val i = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)

val testing = ArrayList<testparcel>()

i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("extraextra", testing)
startActivity(i)
}

class SecondActivity :Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.secondActivty_activity)

val testing = this.intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>("extraextra")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is in Java, I am using Kotlin

Comment: I have changed it to Kotlin. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! This worked and helped a lot.